# Oracle ошибка при парсинге json

Tags: json, парсер, oracle, plsql

Есть ресурс к которому обращаюсь по API и получаю ответ в виде JSON. Там есть пагинация и на странице 30 заявок, нужно получить заявки с 700 страниц. Код написал и он отрабатывает, но в рандомный момент приходит ошибка например

```
*SQL.sql: Ошибка: (39,1): ORA-20987: Error at line 1, col 16382: Expected value (null, false, true, number, varchar2)
```

или

```
SQL.sql: Ошибка: (39,1): ORA-20987: Error at line 1, col 16382: Expected "}", seeing "<varchar2>"
```

или

```
 SQL.sql: Ошибка: (39,1): ORA-20987: Error at line 1, col 16383: strict mode JSON parser does not allow unquoted literals*
```

Код может отработать как 70 страниц, так и 250. JSON приходит нормальный и ошибки в нём нет. Если отдельно распарсить то всё отрабатывает. Пользуюсь `apex_json.parse`.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А зачем нужен apex_json, если поддержка json уже давно встроена в оракл нативно?

Comment: @ESkri, у нас старый оракл и другой разработчик использует этот пакет, поэтому решил делать так же, но попробую почитать про встроенную поддержку